# Is there a pastebin service with LDIF recognition syntax?

Tags: web-services, ldap, pastebin

As the question asks I was wondering if there's a pastebin service that recognises the LDIF syntax of LDAPs.

Comment: Recognizes it how? It's just text.

Comment: by highlighting LDIF keywords/syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around for yonks, the final answer is there isn't for the moment.